# Onclick listeners on views in recycler view row

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a recycler view made up for rows. Each row has a button and an image. I want to add an onClick listener on each image. How can I do that using android and kotlin? I know how to add an onClick listener on the row but not on the elements of the row?

Here's my code

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import com.sumizeit.sumizeit.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_home.*

class HomeAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private var context: Context
    private var list: ArrayList<HomeRow>

    constructor(context: Context, list: ArrayList<HomeRow>){
        this.context = context
        this.list = list
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val vHolder = holder as YourViewHolder
        Picasso.get().load(list[position].image1).into(vHolder.txtImage1);
        Picasso.get().load(list[position].image2).into(vHolder.txtImage2);
        Picasso.get().load(list[position].image3).into(vHolder.txtImage3);
        Picasso.get().load(list[position].image4).into(vHolder.txtImage4);
        Picasso.get().load(list[position].image5).into(vHolder.txtImage5);

        vHolder.txtImage1.setOnClickListener {
            //TODO something..
            Intent(context, BookDetailActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("bookId", list[position].id1)
            }
        }

        vHolder.txtImage2.setOnClickListener {
            //TODO something..
            Intent(context, BookDetailActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("bookId", list[position].id2)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.home_row, parent, false)
        return YourViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    var onItemClick: ((pos: Int, view: View) -> Unit)? = null
    inner class YourViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            onItemClick?.invoke(adapterPosition, v)
        }
        val txtImage1 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView1)
        val txtImage2 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView2)
        val txtImage3 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView3)
        val txtImage4 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView4)
        val txtImage5 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView5)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }
    }
}
```

in Activity

```
       var adp = HomeAdapter(this, listHomeRow);
       rv.adapter = adp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code

```
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            onItemClick?.invoke(adapterPosition, v)
        }
        val txtImage1 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView1)
        val txtImage2 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView2)
        val txtImage3 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView3)
        val txtImage4 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView4)
        val txtImage5 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView5)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }
    }
```

to

```
inner class YourViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            onItemClick?.invoke(adapterPosition, v)
        }
        val txtImage1 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView1)
        val txtImage2 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView2)
        val txtImage3 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView3)
        val txtImage4 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView4)
        val txtImage5 = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView5)

        init {
            txtImage1.setOnClickListener{
                Intent(context, BookDetailActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("bookId", list[layoutPosition].id1)
                context.startActivity(this)
                }
            }
            txtImage2.setOnClickListener{
                Intent(context, BookDetailActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("bookId", list[layoutPosition].id2)
                context.startActivity(this)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and remove clickListener in your bindViewHolder() method. try this bro.

Answer (score 1):

In anticipation of your adapter, I made some sample code.

```
class CategoryAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private var context: Context
    private var list: ArrayList<YourItem>

    constructor(context: Context, list: ArrayList<YourItem>){
        this.context = context
        this.list = list
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false)
        YourViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val cameraViewHolder = holder as YourViewHolder

        cameraViewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener {
            //TODO something..
            Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("category", list[position].name)
            }
        }
    }

    internal class YourViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.your_image
    }
}
```

> New, Try this

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import com.sumizeit.sumizeit.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_home.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.home_row.*

class HomeAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private var context: Context
    private var list: ArrayList<HomeRow>

    constructor(context: Context, list: ArrayList<HomeRow>){
        this.context = context
        this.list = list
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val vHolder = holder as YourViewHolder

        with(Picasso.get()){
            load(list[position].image1).into(vHolder.txtImage1)
            load(list[position].image2).into(vHolder.txtImage2)
            load(list[position].image3).into(vHolder.txtImage3)
            load(list[position].image4).into(vHolder.txtImage4)
            load(list[position].image5).into(vHolder.txtImage5)
        }

        vHolder.txtImage1.setOnClickListener {
            //TODO something..
            Intent(context, BookDetailActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("bookId", list[position].id1)
                context.startActivity(this)
            }
        }

        vHolder.txtImage2.setOnClickListener {
            //TODO something..
            Intent(context, BookDetailActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("bookId", list[position].id2)
                context.startActivity(this)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.home_row, parent, false)
        return YourViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    inner class YourViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val txtImage1 = itemView.imageView1
        val txtImage2 = itemView.imageView2
        val txtImage3 = itemView.imageView3
        val txtImage4 = itemView.imageView4
        val txtImage5 = itemView.imageView5

    }
}
```

Comment: how do we initialize the contxt? when we initialize the adapteR?

Comment: yes, 
var adp = CategoryAdapter(list, YourActivity.this);

Comment: See my question again. I did what you said. but doesn't work

Comment: To move the activity screen, you must call startActivity, and the Onclick listener in YourViewHolder seems meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the adapter where the `ImageView` is bound. Just use that reference to set the `onClickListener`. You're probably doing it inside the `onBindViewHolder` method or inside the ViewHolder.

Comment: Provide us with some code to know exactly what you're doing. Also this video might help you [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69C1ljfDvl0)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom view for the recycler view :

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/info_card_view"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_card_radius"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/dimen_card_elevation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_common_margin">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item_constraintlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_card_padding">

       ...

        <!--Image corresponding to info-->
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_pexel"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_common_margin"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:imageUrl="@{pexelPhoto.src.medium}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>

       ...

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Create a custom viewholder which will have click listener for the image in recyclerview row :

```
class PhotosViewHolder(private val viewBinding: ViewDataBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewBinding.root) {
    fun bind(data: Any, listener: OnItemClickListener) {
        viewBinding.setVariable(BR.pexelPhoto, data)
        (viewBinding.root.findViewById(R.id.image_pexel) as ImageView).setOnClickListener { _ ->
            listener.onThumbnailClick(data as PexelPhoto)
        }
        viewBinding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

You can check the complete source here for reference : https://github.com/spartan-1/PexelsApp